# How to get the Size of a webpage resource like javascript, css, image, etc

Tags: javascript, html, performance, metadata, resource-timing-api

The [w3c resource Timing API](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/) gives a mechanism to find the timing details of loading a resource like .js, .css, .gif, font, etc. However, current implementations haven't yet implemented returning the size of the resource (http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/#performanceresourcetiming transferSize).

Till the time browser vendors implement the attribute "transferSize", how are application developers or tool vendors to determine the size of a given resource?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot use JavaScript to access resources length.
The only ways that I found using scripts are with `PHP`, for example [this old StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file) that basically describes [this method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#92462) as the best to retrieve the length of remote files, such as `css`, `js`, etc. without downloading them.
As you said it hasn't been implemented yet a property to access the size of the files.
I also link you [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624268/display-file-size-of-externally-loaded-resources-for-an-html-page) because it mentions a tool developed by Google called [speedtracer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/get-started) that allows you to analyze your page loading time and other things.

I hope this helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

Fast-forward many years later...

```
var Url=''; // paste a resource url in here    

fetch(Url).then(response=>{


 // add code here to process the result or send to a container like in this simple example:

 Z.innerHTML=Number(response.headers.get('Content-Length'));


}).catch(error=>{Z.innerHTML='error';});
```

Container waiting for the async result to arrive...

```
<span id="Z"></span>
```